# Parsing HTML5 data-attribute to document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, dom, queryselector

I have three HTML buttons with ids and classes. Two of them also hold data attributes.

The data attributes are for the element they should change the style display property for.

The basic idea is to show or hide paragraph elements.
I am trying to reduce repetitive code by using querySelectors and for loops instead of having multiple event listeners.
I am stuck at writing the function that starts on line 31 of the codepen. I have tried: document.querySelector(classbtns[i].getAttribute('data-value')).style.display = "inline";
and I am getting: TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

I have retained and commented out earlier code-blocks to help give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

Please see my code and link to the codepen below:

html:

```
 <p id="toy-pictures-latest" class="panel">Latest Toy Pictures</p><br>
         <p id="toy-pictures-greatest" class="panel">Greatest Toy Pictures</p>

Toy Pictures
<button type="button" id="btnlatest" data-value="toy-pictures-latest" class="buttons">Latest</button>
<button type="button" id="btngreatest" data-value="toy-pictures-greatest class="buttons">Greatest</button></details></li>
<button type="button" id="clear-btn">Clear</button>
```

css:

```
 #toy-pictures-latest.panel{
    display: inline;
}

#toy-pictures-greatest.panel{
        display: inline;
}
```

js:

```
/*function fgreatest() {
   document.getElementById('toy-pictures-greatest').style.display = "inline";
   }*/

//The following function clears the p elements in class "panel" by changing the display value in css

function clearall()
{
var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel'), i;  
console.log("exe");  
for (i = 0; i < panels.length; ++i) {
  panels[i].style.display = "none";
}

}  

//This is the previous version of the querySelector.
//It required a new function for each <p> element id 

/*const classbtns = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");

 for (let i = 0; i < classbtns.length; i++) {
     classbtns[i].addEventListener("click", fgreatest);
 }*/

//This is the attempt to grab the name of the element
//from the html data value property and change the css //style display to inline

 const classbtns = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");
 
  for (let i = 0; i < classbtns.length; i++) {
     classbtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     
     document.querySelector(classbtns[i].getAttribute('data-value')).style.display = "inline";
      });
  }

document.getElementById('clear-btn').addEventListener("click", clearall);
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/vYGjMqR?editors=1111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found two issues:

1. In HTML, data-value tag for button "btngreatest" is missing end quote.

   <button type="button" id="btngreatest" data-value="toy-pictures-greatest class="buttons">
2. Since you want to select panels by ID, you should prefix with '#'

   document.querySelector('#'+ classbtns[i].getAttribute('data-value')).style.display = "inline";

Comment: No problem. Also as @nzn states in another answer, for your case, better to use "document.getElementById"

Comment: Sure but then I wouldn't have learned about querySelector.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting an element by Id with document.querySelector you need to preface with "#" so that would be:

```
document.querySelector('#' + classbtns[i].getAttribute('data-value')).style.display = "inline";
      });
```

But then you might as well just use

```
document.getElementById(classbtns[i].getAttribute('data-value')).style.display = "inline";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as an additive to the solutions already it may be worth taking into consideration the good old MDN on getting the data attribute:

> [...], but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringmap you can read out via a dataset property.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

I personally would also go for the target of of the event. Something like:

```
const attachListener = btn => btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => document.getElementById(e.target.dataset.value).style.display = 'inline';

clsBtns.forEach(attachListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more **current** and simplified clean approach by using `forEach` method and targeting the actual element we have clicked on using `event.target` method

[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will ensure you are targeting the correct element to get its `data-value` - This approach is *better* if you have alot of buttons and nested inside each other.

You can also use newly `dataset` approach as well **instead** of using the `getAtribute` method

Using [data.set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

```
 document.querySelector("#" + e.target.dataset.value).style.display = "inline";
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
function clearall() {
  var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')
  panels.forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = "none";
  });
}

const classbtns = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");
classbtns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.querySelector("#" + e.target.getAttribute('data-value')).style.display = "inline";
  })
})

//clear al;
document.getElementById('clear-btn').addEventListener("click", clearall);
```

```css
#toy-pictures-latest.panel {
  display: none;
}

#toy-pictures-greatest.panel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="toy-pictures-latest" class="panel">Latest Toy Pictures</p><br>
<p id="toy-pictures-greatest" class="panel">Greatest Toy Pictures</p>

<br>
Toy Pictures
<button type="button" id="btnlatest" data-value="toy-pictures-latest" class="buttons">Latest</button>

<button type="button" id="btngreatest" data-value="toy-pictures-greatest" class="buttons">Greatest</button>

<button type="button" id="clear-btn">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Thank you AlwaysHelping. I previously attempted some examples that used "forEach" but I didn't get them working. I have put your code in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/gOrzNPp) to test it out.

It is good to have both methods so I can test on different browsers. Thank you.

Comment: @caston Happy to help mate :) ForEach works on all browsers these days as stated in MDN. I am guessing your approach might be be correct with using it. Let me know if i can help any futher mate. Leave me a comment if you get stuck :)

Comment: This was a nice little distraction from working on the float wireframes I need to do for my course but now I must get back to them.

Comment: I am now trying to add '-footer' but am unsure of the exact syntax.
I have tried ```document.querySelector('#' + classbtns[i].getAttribute('data-value') + '-footer').style.display = "inline"; });  ```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/j354374/pen/LYNrOeo)

Comment: @caston sorry i am not sure what that is you are talking about ? Could you elaborate  please ideally you can add another question if its different issue ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly I am trying to add a string of text to the query so that I can display a footer as well without changing the js code too much. I think I just have the wrong syntax. I made a new code pen to demonstrate what I am trying to do. It should be the same button.

Comment: @caston here is working code for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ja1sqz2v/ - you have an extra bracket which was breaking the code and also you query for footer was outside the click function.

Comment: You legend. Thank you.

Comment: @caston happy to help mate